# mvc signalr chat - identity user role as prefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-identity, isinrole

so I'm having troubles using MVC Identity user roles as prefixes in my signalr chat.

This is jQuery inside a script tag in the view.

the view:

```
var admin = "@User.IsInRole("Administrator");"
// Add the message to the page.
  if (admin)  {
  $('#discussion').append('<li class="list-group-item"><strong>' + today + ' - [Admin] - ' + htmlEncode(name) + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
  }

  else {
  $('#discussion').append('<li class="list-group-item"><strong>' + today + ' - ' + htmlEncode(name) + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
  }
```

But the thing now is when a Admin views the chat, everyone that types in chat got the Admin prefix for HIM, and opposite.

Is it any way to make this work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you should provide more details. This looks like `jquery`, even though you said it's your view. Is it a `<script>` inside your view? When is this code executed? When your javascript receives an event from signalr?

Comment: Yes, it's jQuery within a script tag in the view.